# Find a formula for $\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})$ for positive integer n.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, gamma-function

Find a formula for $\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})$ for positive integer n.

---

I know the following relations;  $\Gamma (z+1)=z\Gamma (z)$ and $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$

Please give me a way how to show this. Thank you.

Comment: If you know $\Gamma(\frac12)$, this is trivial. If you don't, you should.

Comment: Yes $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ @Did

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Integers_and_half-integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma\left(n+\frac12\right)
&=\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\frac12\frac32\frac52\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2}\\
&=\sqrt\pi\frac{1\cdot\color{#A0A0A0}{2}\cdot3\cdot\color{#A0A0A0}{4}\cdot5\cdot\color{#A0A0A0}{6}\cdots(2n-1)\cdot\color{#A0A0A0}{2n}}{2^n(\color{#A0A0A0}{2}\cdot\color{#A0A0A0}{4}\cdot\color{#A0A0A0}{6}\cdots\color{#A0A0A0}{2n})}\\
&=\sqrt\pi\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!}
\end{align}
$$

---

To match the form in the question:

For even $n$,
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac n2\right)=\left(\frac n2-1\right)!
$$
For odd $n$,
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac n2\right)=\sqrt\pi\frac{(n-1)!}{2^{n-1}\frac{n-1}{2}!}
$$

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 4):

If $n$ is even, use that second identity.  Otherwise, use that first identity to relate $\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$ to $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt\pi$.